# Bootstrap - spacing between form-inline elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 3, inline forms (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) -
I cannot seem to find the reason for the spacing between `.form-group` classes.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ek1oa3s/1/

The reason I'm asking is because on my dev environment I have this spacing, but after I build with gulp, in the deployment version - the spacing is gone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That space is generated by the property `inline-block` is compared to treating the elements as text, if you have on your markup each element on a new line this generates a space and each element is a "new word".

**Check the Snippet**

```css
section {
  background:white;
  margin:20px auto;
}
div {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  width:30%;
  margin:20px auto;
  background:red;
  border:thin solid orange
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

I guess when you build with gulp you minify your html making your html with no spaces between items and then has no space making all elements "one word".

**Check the Snippet**

```css
section {
  background:white;
  margin:20px auto;
}
div {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  width:30%;
  margin:20px auto;
  background:red;
  border:thin solid orange
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</section>
```

---

To solve this you can add on your style a `margin-right` value like:

```
.form-inline .form-group {
  margin-right:4px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have spent hours to find the root cause. 
I was using bootstrap with angular.

Answer (score 2):

Add margin-right or left to your form-group inside your form

Comment: I knew how to solve it, I wanted to know the reason. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can see on the developer tools where the spacing comes from.

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```